# A theorem of Stickelberger on the number of prime ideals in a decomposition

Tags: reference-request, nt.number-theory

Suppose that $p$ is unramified in a number field $K$ of degree $n$. Apparently, Stickelberger proved that $\big( \frac{Disc(K)}{p}\big) = (-1)^{n - g}$, where $g$ is the number of prime ideal factors over $(p)$ in $K$.

Is there a convenient reference for this fact?

Thank you! -Frank

Comment: http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1427

Comment: Frank, this is proved in Hasse's "Number Theory". 

Comment: Stickelberger's paper appeared in the proceedings of the 1st ICM in 1897. A related, but simpler, result goes back to Pellet in 1878: for an odd prime $p$ and squarefree polynomial $h(x)$ in ${\mathbf F}_p[x]$ of degree $n$ with $g$ monic irreducible factors, $(\frac{{\rm disc} h}{p}) = (-1)^{n-g}$.

Comment: Stickelberger's original formulation is a little gem : *Die Diskriminante des Körpers $\Omega$ ist durch die Primzahl $p$ nicht
teilber, wenn $p$ ein Produkt von lauter verschiedenen Primidealen in 
ist; zugleich ist sie, wenn  ungerade, quadratischer Rest oder Nichtrest
von $p$, je nachdem die Anzahl der in $p$ aufgehenden Primideale von geradem
Grade eine gerade oder ungerade ist, oder je nachdem die Anzahl aller
Primfaktoren von $p$ dem Grade des Körpers kongruent ist nach dem Modul
Zwei oder nicht.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First reduce the question to the local case--This can be done since after base change to   $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$, $K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_{p}=K_1 \times...\times K_{g}$, the trace form is the orthogonal sum of the local trace forms so the discriminant is the product of the local discriminants, and then use that the Legendre symbol is multiplicative. Now, since $p$ is unramified the extension $K_{i}/\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is a cyclic extension of degree $f_{i}$, notation as usual, with Galois group generated by $\sigma$. We want to show that 
 $\left ( \frac{disc(K_i)}{p}\right)= (-1)^{f_i -1}$. This is done in the exact same way one proves that a cubic extension is Galois iff its discriminant is a square; just notice that $(-1)^{f_i -1}$ is the the signature of $\sigma$ under the regular representation of $Gal(K_{i}/\mathbb{Q}_{p})$.

**Remark:** If you, like Conway, like the notation $p=-1$ for the infinite prime then the above proof works at that prime too. Just read Kronecker symbol instead of Legendre, and what one gets is the usual "sign of discriminant is $(-1 )^{s}$ "

Comment: This proof goes back to Hensel, Crelle, 1905.  